# Howto use readlink with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, linux, glibc, uclibc

### Problem:

On a linux machine I want to read the target string of a link. From documentation I have found the following code sample (without error processing):

```
struct stat sb;
ssize_t r;
char * linkname;

lstat("<some link>", &sb);
linkname = malloc(sb.st_size + 1);
r = readlink("/proc/self/exe", linkname, sb.st_size + 1);
```

The probelm is that sb.st_size returns 0 for links on my system.

So how does one allocate memory dynamically for readline on such systems?

Many thanks!

---

### One possible solution:

For future reference. Using the points made by jilles:

```
struct stat sb;
ssize_t r = INT_MAX;
int linkSize = 0;
const int growthRate = 255;

char * linkTarget = NULL;

// get length of the pathname the link points to
if (lstat("/proc/self/exe", &sb) == -1) {   // could not lstat: insufficient permissions on directory?
    perror("lstat");
    return;
}

// read the link target into a string
linkSize = sb.st_size + 1 - growthRate;
while (r >= linkSize) { // i.e. symlink increased in size since lstat() or non-POSIX compliant filesystem
    // allocate sufficient memory to hold the link
    linkSize += growthRate;
    free(linkTarget);
    linkTarget = malloc(linkSize);
    if (linkTarget == NULL) {           // insufficient memory
        fprintf(stderr, "setProcessName(): insufficient memory\n");
        return;
    }

    // read the link target into variable linkTarget
    r = readlink("/proc/self/exe", linkTarget, linkSize);
    if (r < 0) {        // readlink failed: link was deleted?
        perror("lstat");
        return;
    }
}
linkTarget[r] = '\0';   // readlink does not null-terminate the string
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

POSIX says the `st_size` field for a symlink shall be set to the length of the pathname in the link (without `'\0'`). However, the `/proc` filesystem on Linux is not POSIX-compliant. (It has more violations than just this one, such as when reading certain files one byte at a time.)

You can allocate a buffer of a certain size, try `readlink()` and retry with a larger buffer if the buffer was not large enough (`readlink()` returned as many bytes as fit in the buffer), until the buffer is large enough.

Alternatively you can use `PATH_MAX` and break portability to systems where it is not a compile-time constant or where the pathname may be longer than that (POSIX permits either).

Comment: Thanks for the point about the /proc filesystem. I was not aware of this. So st_size "should" work anywhere except in /proc. It looks like an iterative approach has to be used as a fall-back solution for universal code.

Comment: @ArikRaffaelFunke: At best the `st_size` field is only indicative anyway, because the link could be changed between the `lstat()` call and the `readlink()` call.  So you need to be prepared to handle the size being insufficient anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers don't mention it, but there is the `realpath` function, that does exactly what you want, which is specified by POSIX.1-2001.

```
char *realpath(const char *path, char *resolved_path);
```

from the manpage:

> realpath()  **expands  all  symbolic links** and resolves references to
>   /./, /../ and extra '/' characters in the null-terminated string named
>   by path to produce  a  canonicalized absolute pathname.

`realpath` also handles the dynamic memory allocation for you, if you want. Again, excerpt from the manpage:

> If  resolved_path  is  specified  as NULL, then realpath() uses
>   malloc(3) to allocate a buffer of up to PATH_MAX bytes to hold the
>   resolved pathname, and returns a pointer  to this buffer.  The caller
>   should deallocate this buffer using free(3).

As a simple, complete example:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>    

int
resolve_link (const char *filename)
{
  char *res = realpath(filename, NULL);
  if (res == NULL)
    {
      perror("realpath failed");
      return -1;
    }

  printf("%s -> %s\n", filename, res);
  free(res);

  return 0;
}

int
main (void)
{
  resolve_link("/proc/self/exe");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wish more library functions had the option to automatically allocate the string buffer. Why don't they?

Answer (score 1):

st_size does not give the correct answer on /proc.

Instead you can malloc PATH_MAX, or pathconf(_PC_PATH_MAX) bytes. That should be enough for most cases. If you want to be able to handle paths longer than that, you can call readlink in a loop and reallocate your buffer if the readlink return value indicates that the buffer is too short. Note though that many other POSIX functions simply assume PATH_MAX is enough.

Comment: Unfortunately PATH_MAX does not help. On my system it is 4096 but on an ext3 filesystem there is nothing preventing you from having paths longer than that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit puzzled as to why `st_size` is zero. Per POSIX:

> For symbolic links, the st_mode member shall contain meaningful information when used with the file type macros. The file mode bits in st_mode are unspecified. The structure members st_ino, st_dev, st_uid, st_gid, st_atim, st_ctim, and st_mtim shall have meaningful values and the value of the st_nlink member shall be set to the number of (hard) links to the symbolic link. The value of the st_size member shall be set to the length of the pathname contained in the symbolic link not including any terminating null byte.

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lstat.html

If `st_size` does not work, I think your only option is to dynamically allocate a buffer and keep resizing it larger as long as the return value of `readlink` is equal to the buffer size.

Comment: Even if `st_size` does work, the link destination could be changed between the `lstat()` call and the `readlink()` call.

Comment: Indeed, in which case you'll have to detect truncation and retry.

Answer (score 0):

The [manpage for `readlink(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) says it will silently truncate if the buffer is too small.  If you truly want to be unbounded (and don't mind paying some cost for extra work) you can start with a given allocation size and keep increasing it and re-trying the `readlink` call.  You can stop growing the buffer when the next call to `readlink` returns the same string it did for the last iteration.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve with the lstat?

You should be able to get the target with just the following

```
char buffer[1024];
ssize_t r = readlink ("/proc/self/exe", buffer, 1024);
buffer[r] = 0;

printf ("%s\n", buffer);
```

If you're trying to get the length of the file name size, I don't think st_size is the right variable for that... But that's possibly a different question.

Comment: This does not help as I am looking for a way to dynamically allocate the required size. You are implicitly limiting the length of paths to 1024 character. This will be enough in most cases - but there is no guarantee.